# Can we have $\nabla\cdot B \neq 0$ and still no magnetic work?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

I had an argument with a friend who says that it's possible to have a force that does no work on monopoles with $\nabla \cdot B \neq 0$.

I believe this is not possible, as if we imagine approaching two monopoles towards each other, the fact that $\nabla \cdot B \neq 0$ would imply that there is a radial component to the force, which then implies that this action would require some work.

I haven't been reading all the theory of Dirac monopoles, but the way it is formalized seems to be in accordance with my belief.

The question is : does this has to be the case, or could we imagine a way to have a non-zero divergence of the magnetic field with still no magnetic work ?

Comment: Well - if you are moving tangentially to the force, there will be no work. It's not quite clear what you are asking - are you talking about two magnetic monopoles? What, if any, constraints are you imposing? If both are fixed, they do no work. You have to be more careful in your formulation.

Comment: Yes I am talking about two magnetic monopoles that are being approached toward each other, without imposing any constraint, just setting $\nabla \cdot B \neq 0$